# Best datatype to store and retrieve a Google Place's place_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, google-places-api

I'm working on a Rails application that would store the `place_id` of a business provided by the Google Places API. Is there are a better way of saving the place_id in the database instead of saving it as a `varchar` / `character varying` datatype?

I'm using Postgres as my back-end. Any suggestions for datatype which will make the lookup process quick will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API doesn't specifically list a type for `place_id`, but in its examples it always uses an alphanumeric value, i.e.:

```
ChIJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk
D9iJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk
ChIJqwS6fjiuEmsRJAMiOY9MSms
ChIJLfySpTOuEmsRsc_JfJtljdc
```

Therefore using `character varying` is best.

Comment: If we store and retrieve businesses based on varchar related IDs, wouldn't it affect performance? Any alternatives you can think of to speed it up?